# Is there any way to remove cross symbol from input fields in IE browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Whenever I enter something to the input box in IE browser, a cross symbol appears at the other end. I am using CSS to add card image to display card type using jquery.addClass at the same place where the cross symbol appears and the card image overlaps with the cross symbol. Please let me know if there is any way I can remove the cross symbol.

Comment: can you please show us the demo or provide any jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this works in IE10 and above, I haven't tried other browsers..

```
.someinput::-ms-clear {
   display: none;
}
```

Or if you want to remove the padding as well:

```
.someinput::-ms-clear {
   width : 0;
   height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robin. This works.

Comment: @abhiagNitk In that case, would you kindly mark my response as the solutions? Thanks.